# IIS Default Document rewrite rule

Tags: iis, default-document

I want to create a default document called default and in that document I want it to rewrite the URL so instead of going www.bob.com it should instead go to www.bob.com/uv

Right now this is being done through URL rewrite rules, with patterns and all kinds of complications. I saw this done directly in the default document once, I cant remember if it was default.htm or .html or .aspx, using one line of code and I was very intrigued but I have not found it since then and no good examples have come up in my google searching. Does anyone have a link or could write the single line of code to add \uv to the url? Is there a really good example of it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add which ever default page you want from IIS Manager ->  -> Default Document - > Add (on right side) or by adding below in your web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However this is a rewrite i.e. this will load default.aspx when you browse www.bob.com (URL remains same but the page is actually loaded).

If you want to actually change the URL (redirect) then with the same configuration above this below line in default.aspx

```
<%Response.Redirect("home.aspx")%>
```